# SQL current time stamp Donde seleciones un dia especifico del mes anterior al presente

Tags: sql, sql-server

estoy buscando una manera de comparar un dato de my tabla en SQL server para obtener la lista de registros apartir de una fecha

```
SELECT * FROM asistencias where fecha >= (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP-15)
```

(muestra los resultados actual mente apratir de la fecha actual -15 dias)

mi consulta real es:

```
SELECT * FROM asistencia where id_usuario=$Id_usuario and fecha > '2018-07-25' and fecha < '2018-08-25' and asistencia = '0'
```

como el periodo actual tiene que ser automatico las fechas tienen que genererse de manera logica

Comment: Que es lo que te sucede cuando disparas tu consulta actual??, por lo pronto en vez de utilizar (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - 15), utiliza GETDATE() - 15, intentalo y cuentanos.

Comment: ya lo intente y me muestra el mismo resultado, actual mente mi intencion es encontrar de manera logica los resultados entre dos fechas, algo asi: SELECT * FROM asistencia where id_usuario=$Id_usuario and fecha > '2018-07-25' and fecha < '2018-08-25' and asistencia = '0' pero que las fechas siempre sean el periodo entre el 25 del mes pasado y el presente

Comment: edito la preguntapara definir mejor mi duda

Comment: Entonces lo que deseas hacer es un store procedure por lo que veo. Y por lo que te refieres a manera lógica, es realmente dinámica, que no se encuentre quemado en el código el intervalo de fechas.

Comment: si, actual mente lo mas parecido que tengo que : SELECT * FROM asistencia where id_usuario=$Id_usuario and fecha > Convert(datetime, DateAdd(month, -1, Convert(date, GetDate(),25))) and fecha < Convert(datetime, DateAdd(month, 1, Convert(date, GetDate(),25))) and asistencia = '0' aun que no lo entiendo muy bien

Answer (score 2):

Usando `DAY(15)` le puedes restar o sumar los días. Sería algo como esto:

```
SELECT * 
FROM asistencia 
WHERE id_usuario=$Id_usuario AND 
      fecha > GetDate()-DAY(15) AND 
      fecha < GetDate()+DAY(15) AND 
      asistencia = '0'
```

Comment: Adjunta una explicación a tu respuesta, no solo el código sin mas. [**_Aquí_**](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) puedes ver como corresponde responder.

Comment: Usando DAY(15) le puedes restar o sumar los dias

Comment: gracias, es una gran solucion . sin embargo eso solo me mostrara el dia actual recorrido +/- 15 dias es decir , si quiero encontrar la lista de sistencia apartir del dia 20 hoy dia 31 solo me sotrara apartr del dia 16 lo que es incorrecto

Comment: Entonces tú lo que necesitas es poder ver a x días atrás? Es que no entiendo muy bien lo qué necesitas